# Search for ALT code in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Database, where I want to search for an AltI code ALT+192 ( └ ) in 1 table.

When I search on the '└' character right now, it recognizes the symbol as an L and gives me all values with a "normal" L.

How can I run a query to search up the row which contains the above symbol? I currently run into an error when exporting my data due to this character.

Comment: Have you tried what is described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23327470/4725649)?

Comment: the 'N prefix did the trick, thank you.